# Rally SDK 2.0 Is there a way to get the Kanban state change date

Tags: rally, kanban

Trying to retrieve the Kanban state change date for a User Story.  So for each Kanban state the day it occurred.  Is there an object or attribute that contains that information?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only way to capture this information would be by querying and parsing the RevisionHistory collection on the Story - which can be somewhat cumbersome and slow.

If your organization is in the LookbackAPI preview program, I would recommend using an LBAPI-based query which can capture state changes via a single REST query.